# getting the status code of a HTTP redirected page

Tags: ruby, curl, curb

I'm using curb to test some URLs in Ruby:

```
require 'curb'

def test_url()
  c = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection") do |curl|
    curl.follow_location= true
    curl.head = true
  end

  c.perform
  puts "status => " + c.status
  puts "body => " + c.body_str
  puts "final url => " + c.last_effective_url
end

test_url
```

This outputs:

```
status => 301 Moved Permanently
body => 
final url => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection
```

In this case, `www.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection` redirects to `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection`.

As you can see, I am getting a 301 status. How can I get the status of the final response code?

In this case, it is 200 because the document is found. I checked the libcurl documentation and found a flag `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`.

What is the equivalent in the curb library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

I cloned the curb source and grepped for :

```
last_effective_url
```

In the function below it was the equivalent for the response code, in curb_easy.c, line 2435.

Note to self, "Use the source Luke"!

UPDATE:

The answer is `response_code`
In my case the code looks like so:

```
c = Curl::Easy.new(HOST_NAME) do |curl|
    curl.follow_location = true
    curl.head = true
  end

  c.perform
  puts url + " => " + c.response_code.to_s
```

Comment: please put your modified code as your answer. So that no one in future need to look back the source code.

Comment: I need to wait 2 days before im allowed to do that

Comment: That I know,I am talking about the fix you did in your code,to wrote down in your answer.